# ASP.NET MVC - Unable to access model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am making a page and this page has Table. I'm trying to make a filtering system in Table. I made the filtering system, but I'm having problems.

First of all my codes:

```
`Index.cshtml`:

    @model List<StudentApp.Models.Entity.StudentTable>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Manage Student";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<br />
<h1>Manage Student</h1>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "StudentTable", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.theErrorIsHere, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ClassT, new { @class = "form-control"})
        <b>Student Name:</b> @Html.TextBox("p");
        <input type="submit" value="Ara">
    </p>
}
<table id="tbl1" class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Student ID
        </th>
        <th>
            Student Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Student Class
        </th>
        <th>
            Edit
        </th>
        <th>
            Delete
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Id
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Class.ClassName
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/StudentTable/EditStudent/@item.Id" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/StudentTable/Delete/@item.Id" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<a href="/StudentTable/AddStudent"  class="btn btn-primary">Add Student</a>
```

And I am having this problem:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `@model StudentApp.Models.Entity.StudentTable` muste be `@model List<StudentApp.Models.Entity.StudentTable>` in your Index.cshtml

Comment: Thanks for answers. Now I am getting an error like this: https://imgur.com/a/mQ9mF1E

Comment: i think you are inside the loop and need to get the class of a student. you can access the student  by the 'item' property in the loop and get item.Class

Comment: Hello. I misplaced `DropDownListFor`. I should have put it outside the loop. I'm confused. Sorry. How can I use it outside of the loop? I updated the `Index.cshtml` codes in the topic. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: since this is another problem, better to create add this as a new Question on stackoverflow

Comment: I understand, sorry. So I'm opening a new topic.

Comment: help pls. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73274580/asp-net-mvc-access-issue-in-dropdownlistfor